# Meaning of *= in Java

Tags: java, notation

I see an unfamiliar notation in the Android source code: `*=`

For example: `density *= invertedRatio;`

I am not familiar with the star-equals notation.  Can somebody explain it?

Comment: Other people have already answered your question, but I felt that you can also write "variable ++" or "variable --", which means that the variable count increases by 1, or decreases by 1, respectively.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`density *= invertedRatio;` is a shortened version of `density = density * invertedRatio;`

This notation comes from C.

Comment: I would probably call it syntactic sugar rather than acronym. :p

Comment: Comes from C?  That is why I thought it looked eerily similar to a pointer!  But it aint...

Comment: Note that a magic cast might be inserted. For instance, if `density` is `short` it'll still compile and might even work.

Answer (score 22):

In Java, the `*=` is called a multiplication compound assignment operator.

It's a shortcut for

```
density = density * invertedRatio;
```

Same abbreviations are possible e.g. for:

```
String x = "hello "; x += "world" // results in "hello world"
int y = 100; y -= 42; // results in y == 58
```

and so on.

Answer (score 8):

It is a shorthand assignment operator. It takes the following form:

```
variable op= expression;
```

is short form of

```
variable = variable op expression;
```

So,

```
density *= invertedRatio;
```

is equivalent to

```
density = density * invertedRatio;
```

See the following link for more info:

[How to Use Assignment Operators in Java](http://www.ehow.com/how_2094990_use-assignment-operators-java.html)

Comment: This is not strictly true, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator

Comment: @xxpor Thanks for the insight! Its a new piece of knowledge. +1 for comment.

Answer (score 3):

Just like Da said, it's short for `density = density * invertedRatio;` - it's nothing Android specific, it's standard Java. You will find this (and similar operators) in many languages with a C-like syntax.