# difference between a += b and a = a + b

Tags: java, operators

In Java, I really wonder is there a difference between using `a += b;` or `a = a + b;` . Which one should I use principally? I know that first one is something like shortcut but does the compiler get those two indications differently?

Comment: Please specify language.

Comment: Which language? In which context? Depending on the language, it may also depend on the type of `a` and `b`.

Comment: look up "[sytactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)".

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator

Comment: The a+=b thing is useful to make more concise instruction but not necessarily the easiest to understand! That depends only of you I guess.

Comment: @Mysticial I've just checked the link. "wow". those were really different. Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See the [Java language specification, 15.26.2 Compound assignment operators](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5304)

To quote the relevant parts:

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1
>   is evaluated only once.

```
short x = 3;
x += 4.6;
```

> and results in x having the value 7 because it is equivalent to:

```
short x = 3;
x = (short)(x + 4.6);
```

So it is more than syntactic sugar, as

```
int x = 1;
long a = 2l;
x+= a;
```

compiles, where

```
int x =1;
long a =2l;
x = x+a;
```

gives you a compile error, as was discussed [here on StackOverflow quite recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator)

Comment: How is this different from the link provided previously by Mystical in the comments to the original question?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I'd say it's different in that this answer specifies, before any edit, that there's more to it than syntactic sugar as has been discussed extensively here a few days ago.  And he did provide the link to one these recent questions.

Answer (score 3):

Just syntactic sugar in most languages that I know that would include c, c++, C#, java, javascript..

notable difference noted by Cicada in regards to **c++**:

> On numeric types (int and friends) there is no difference. 
>       On user-defined classes there   may be a difference. 
>       A notable one would be D3DXVECTOR3 from DirectX, for example. 
>       Using + would construct a temporary object while += would not.
>       The latter is about 30% faster.

Comment: It's *not* syntactic sugar in C++.

Comment: Can an overridden operator in C++ be different? That is, override **+** in one way and **+=** other way?

Comment: @rogelware: Yes. (And I wish it couldn't be.)

Comment: @Cicada it has been a while since I used C++, could you please tell me what the difference is between a += b; and a = a + b;?

Comment: yes if it's overridden but in its default state, isn't it essentially the same, or am I missing something?

Comment: @BassamMehanni On numeric types (int and friends) there is no difference. On user-defined classes there may be a difference. A notable one would be D3DXVECTOR3 from DirectX, for example. Using `+` would construct a temporary object while `+=` would not. The latter is about 30% faster.

Comment: @Cicada Thanks, do you mind if I added this to the answer for completeness?

Comment: @BassamMehanni Feel free to do so.

Answer (score 3):

it does depend on the language,  but in c# it is very slightly more efficient to use a += b;.

a is only evaluated once.

in a = a + b, a is evaluated twice.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In most languages that support this notation, `a = a + b` is the same as `a += b`, but it's not always the case.

Here is an example in Python (using Numpy):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1])
>>> b = np.array([2])
>>> c = a
>>> a = a + b
>>> print a
[3]
>>> print c
[1]
```

Here `a = a + b` creates a new array for `a + b` and stores it into `a`. `c`, which was using the same reference as the initial `a` still holds the initial array (with value 1).

```
>>> a = np.array([1])
>>> b = np.array([2])
>>> c = a
>>> a += b
>>> print a
[3]
>>> print c
[3]
```

Here `a += b` re-uses the initial array `a`. As a result, since both `a` and `c` refer to the same array, both `a` and `c` are modified.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it ends up being the same thing.

In some languages `+=` is a separate operator that can be overloaded to do something different.

For instance in Python with lists, the behavior is different (I learned this the hard way)

```
a = [1]
b = [2]
z = a
a = a + b
#z is not modified

a = [1]
b = [2]
z = a
a += b
# z is modified
```

Comment: See the answer below ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773349/difference-between-a-b-and-a-a-b/8773408#8773408 ) for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to everything said above, you can also use the following shortcuts:

**Operator (+=)**

```
x+=y;
```

*same as:*

```
x=x+y;
```

**Operator (-=)**

```
x-=y;
```

*same as:*

```
x=x-y;
```

**Operator (*=)**

```
x*=y;
```

*same as:*

```
x=x*y;
```

**Operator (/=)**

```
x/=y;
```

*same as:*

```
x=x/y;
```

**Operator (%=)**

```
x%=y;
```

*same as :*

```
x=x%y;
```

**Operator (&=)**

```
x&=y;
```

*same as :*

```
x=x&y;
```

**Operator (|=)**

```
x|=y;
```

*same as :*

```
x=x|y;
```

**Operator (^=)**

```
x^=y;
```

*same as :*

```
x=x^y;
```

**Operator (>>=)**

```
x>>=y;
```

*same as*

```
result=x>>y;
```

*The same operation to operator (<<=) and operator (>>>=) .*

Answer (score 1):

I'ld prefer `a += b` over `a = a + b`. First of all it is less to write, second it is more clear what is going on. And when talking about C++ and classes it might be more efficient using +=. Take a look at this sample:

```
class C {
public:
    const C &operator =(const C &rhs) { printf("=\n"); x = rhs.x; return *this; }
    C operator +(const C &rhs) { printf("+\n"); C c; c.x = x + rhs.x; return c; }
    C &operator +=(const C &rhs) { printf("+=\n"); x += rhs.x; return *this; }

    int x;
};
C a, b;
a.x = 1;
b.x = 2;
a += b;     // same as a.operator+=(b)
a = a + b;  // same as a.operator=(a.operator+(b))
```

As you can see with `operator +=` you have less temporary objects and better performance.

Answer (score 0):

It's compiler- (and so implementation-) defined whether the compiler generates different code from the above sources, but one thing is sure: a += b is supposed to be a simpler short-hand notation for a = a + b. (that's why, in general, a sane compiler would generate the same code for both).

Answer (score 0):

No, the compiler doesn't differentiate between the two in output. The only difference is in parsing and possibly in lexical analysis (depending on expansion). You would generally use the shortcut form `+=`. It's just syntactic sugar.