# Why does this assignment not require an explicit cast?

Tags: java, casting, operators

Consider this code:

```
byte b=1;
long l=1000;
b += l;
```

I would expect the last statement to require an explicit cast because,
`b+=l` is evaluated as `b = b+l` and
`(b+l)` part gives an integer.
Integer cannot be assigned to byte without an explicit cast?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java += operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well to start with, `b+l` gives a `long`, not an `int`...

... but compound assignment operators have other behaviour. As per [JLS section 15.26.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

Note the cast to `T`.

Comment: you can observe the difference when you manually write b = b + l; then you will see the error you want :-)

Comment: Sorry, b+l gives a long. And I need to read the oracle docs more. Thanks.