# Primitives float and double: why does f+=d not result in Type Mismatch Error?

Tags: java, primitive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java += operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator)

Code example:

```
    double d = 1;
    float f = 2;
    f += d;  // no error?
    f = f+d; // type mismatch error, should be f = (float) (f+d);
```

So why does `f+=d` **not** produce an error (not even at runtime), although this would decrease the accuracy of `d`?

Comment: The linked dupe is for `int` and `long`, but it's the same situation here with `float` and `double`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the duplicate. I did a lot of searching, but "+=" is a bad term to search for. My apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compount assignment does an implicit cast.

```
a #= b;
```

is equivalent to

```
a = (cast to type of a) (a # b);
```

Another example

```
char ch = '0';
ch *= 1.1; // same as ch = (char)(ch * 1.1);
// ch is now '4'
```

Comment: Merged in [Nambari's anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13822265/1208581), both answers excellent.

Comment: @sulai Improving answers is always welcome. ;)

Answer (score 5):

As per [JLS 15.26.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

That means:

```
f += d;
```

would become as

`f = (float) (f+d);`

Comment: I think you mean `f = (float)(f + d);` ;)

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I merge your excellent answer into Peter Lawrey's answer?

Comment: @sulai: Sure whatever the way you wish.