# How explicit casting perform

Tags: java, casting, int, byte

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java += operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator)

We can add a value into any variable either `b+=8` or `b=b+8` both will return the value adding `8` into the variable `b`. I got the question in my interview, it was

```
byte b=7;
b=b+8; //compile error
```

What would be output, I ticked `compile time error`, since adding `byte` and `int` will be `int` (I believe) and since, we are trying to store `int` value into `byte`. But, when I tried below code myself

```
byte b=7;
b+=8; //OK
```

Then, the above code compiles and run perfectly without any error and return `15`. Now, my question is **why and how** ? I mean, why it doesn't requires explicit casting ?

Comment: may be, since i didn't found the solution. that's why i asked.

Comment: `b=(byte) (b+8)` == `b+=8` != `b=b+8`

Comment: Like @alexvetter said, it indeed does an implicit casting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator discusses that.

Comment: Ya, but that was the one part of my question another question was how ?? i mean how, it perform. But, nevertheless, i'll explore it for more and Thanks everyone.!!

Answer (score 1):

That's the only difference in `b = b + 8` and `b += 8`

Compiler puts the cast automatically.

Comment: i know, but that was not question. I asked how and why ??

Comment: How - it is upto compiler. They can add and remove from code as they want cause they are parsing it.
Why - for better usability. i.e. developer need not worry about cast during implicit operations.