# Why does the Java increment operator allow narrowing operations without explicit cast?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, precision

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java += operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator)

In Java, this is not valid (doesn't compile), as expected:

```
long lng = 0xffffffffffffL;
int i;
i = 5 + lng;    //"error: possible loss of magnitude"
```

But this is perfectly fine (?!)

```
long lng = 0xffffffffffffL;
int i = 5;
i += lng;       //compiles just fine
```

This is obviously a narrowing operation, that can possibly exceed the `int` range. So why doesn't the compiler complain?

Comment: This question invites discussion instead of a clear-cut answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i += lng;`   compound assignment operator cast's implicitly.

```
i+=lng; 
is same as 
i = int(i+lng);
```

FROM [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1
>   is evaluated only once.

Comment: So it seems, but why? It seems to me to go against the gist of the language.

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu, This implicit cast happens without errors because there is no syntax available to make it explicit. For example you wouldn't be able to `*=1.5` an integer otherwise.

Answer (score 14):

This is defined in the [JLS #15.26.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

In other words, `i += lng` performs a cast implicitly.

Comment: not jelous, but i said the same darn thing in my answer a minute befor you and i got no reps.. :P

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR You just rephrased OP's question. assylias got upvoted for referencing the JLS. As opposed to you, he posted that in the **first** revision, and was the first one to post it; you needed about 5 revisions to get there (and only after seeing others' answers).

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR Sorry about that - but I'm certainly not going to give away the 3 hats I just got ;-)

Comment: dammit, is it all about the hats now?? :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes - reputation is way overstated. Only hats count.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik i did reference JLS in my answer too .. but whatever, i am not really greedy abouts reps or hats :P

Comment: @assylias haha, why would you say sorry .. i was just makin a conversation thats all.. +1 anyways to have more reps than the question which is already asked  :)

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR ...in your first revision of the answer, or in sixth? I know which, I've been watching your edits.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik hahah, yeah it was later on i referenced the JLS, but still my answer still reflects what's said in JLS doesn't it ?? lemme know if there's something wrong in my answer :)

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR If you want to know why you didn't get the upvotes, it is because your answer was sitting voteless at the moment assylias posted his; everybody upvoted the clean answer backed with a JLS reference and from that point on it was irrelevant to everybody that there happened to be other zero-score answers below that said exactly the same thing. Learn from this and become a better contributor to StackOverflow. **Especially** because soon you'll be a *k-guy*.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik mark as said earlier, i am not greedy or something. i totally agree with you that my answer wasn't as clear as assylias or NPE, i was only making a conversation :p, and i would love to be a better cobntributor to SO .. :)

Answer (score 3):

The compiler does not complain because, according to [JLS §15.26.2. Compound Assignment Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

Thus,

```
i += lng;
```

is equivalent to

```
i = (int)(i + lng);
```