# Java implicit casts that can lead to precision or magnitude loss?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, precision

I recently [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13949840/11545), while converting some Java code to C#, that Java's increment operator '+=' implicitly casts to the type of LHS:

```
int i = 5;
long lng = 0xffffffffffffL;  //larger than Int.MAX_VALUE
i += lng;                    //allowed by Java (i==4), rejected by C#
```

is equivalent to: ([details here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13949840/11545))

```
int i = 0;
long lng = 0xffffffffffffL;
i = (int)(i + lng);
```

thus silently causing the opportunity for loss of magnitude.

C# is more conscientious about this at compile-time:
    `Cannot convert source type long to target type int.`

Are there other similar situations allowed by Java?

Comment: Possibly because it's not a question about C#, it just referrs to it ??  I find it annoying (but I don't downvote) when people include the `[java]` just because they mention it in the question.

Comment: @Peter Okay, you may have a point. I was in a very C#-y mindset when I asked the question (being neck-deep in fixing C# code that was converted from Java). Never thought of adding tags from the readers' point of view :) [C# tag removed]

Comment: I am just guess here. I find it annoy when people down vote but there is no comment as to why.  It's like telling you; I feel like you have done something wrong, but I am not telling you what or I don't even know what it is myself. ;)

Comment: @Peter so... umm, why remove your answer?

Comment: While it was similar in the example I gave it was not the same an implcit cast. meriton pointed out that you cannot give it value which is out of range and I noted that you cannot write `byte b = 1.0;` but you can write `b += 1.0;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A long can be promoted to a float or double, which results in a loss of accuracy:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float f = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    double d = Long.MAX_VALUE;

    System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println(f);
    System.out.println(d);

}
```

prints

```
9223372036854775807
9.223372E18
9.223372036854776E18
```

I suspect C# does this the same way, though.

Aside from the compound assignment operators you already mentioned, I believe those to be all cases where an implicit conversion can change the value.

Comment: Conversion from `float` to `double` may change ranking by hundreds or orders of magnitude.  Given `float f=1E20; float f2=f*f; double d = 1E300;`, a comparison between `f2` and `(float)d` will correctly regard the values as indistinguishable.  On the other hand, comparing `d` and `(double)f2` will indicate that `d` is *smaller* than `f2`, even though it should be 240 orders of magnitude bigger.

Comment: Your example fails to support your claim, because it uses an *explicit* conversion which can (and in this instance does) change the value. Specifically, we have `((float) d) != d` and `((double) f2) == f2`.