# Difference between variable += value and variable = variable+value;

Tags: java, operators

For example:

```
int a = 10;
a += 1.5;
```

This runs perfectly, but

```
a = a+1.5;
```

this assignment says `Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int`.
So my question is: what is the difference between `+= operator` and `= operator`. Why the first assignment didn't says nothing, but second will. Please explain to me. Just I want to know whether I can use the first assignment to all place or not.

Comment: This question was discussed on SO many-many times. Learn how to use search

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specification section 15.26.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

So the most important difference (in terms of why the second version doesn't compile) is the implicit cast back to the type of the original variable.

Answer (score 9):

```
int a = 10;
a += 1.5;
```

is equivalent to:

```
int a = 10;
a = (int) (a + 1.5);
```

---

In general:

`x += y;` is equivalent to `x = (type of x) (x + y);`

---

See [15.26.2. Compound Assignment Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)

Answer (score 2):

Check this link

```
int a = 10;
a += 1.5;
```

will be treated as

```
int a=10;
a=(int)(a+1.5);
```

As you can found in this link [expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.26.2)

Answer (score 1):

In case of

```
a += 1.5;
```

implicit auto boxing is done

where as here

```
a = a+1.5;
```

you are explicitly adding a int variable to a float/double variable

so to correct it

```
a = a+(int)1.5;
```

or

```
a = (int) (a+1.5);
```