# Operators in java: '+' with '=' vs '+='

Tags: java, operators

I often use both forms: short and long of addition (also subtraction, multiplication, etc.) operator in java. And I thought that this doesn't impact to performance or speed, but I was confused by questions: "Why java creators provided two forms of this operators? And what is the difference between them?" So, what's real difference between two forms:

```
int a = 10, b = 3;
b = b + a;
```

and

```
int a = 10, b = 3;
b += a;
```

Can someone explain me this? May be difference between two forms is hidden at a lower level?
Every book says only: "Java also has compound operators..." but nothing about difference.

Comment: thats because there isn't a difference.

Comment: @StefanPante. No, there is a difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java += operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is really very old. But I want to summarize: I have found in the 
[Java Language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) the next text:

> A compound assignment expression of the form **E1 op= E2** is equivalent
>   to **E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))**, where **T** is the type of **E1**, except that **E1**
>   is evaluated only once.

So, it's enought for understanding!

Answer (score 8):

Consider the following code:

```
int x = 9;
short s = 2;
s = s+x; // Compiler error
s += x;  // Compiles
```

So, basically when you say: `s += x` it means that `s = (short)(s+x)`. And when you use `s = s+x`, the compiler will complain since, it cannot cast `x` from `int` to `short` implicitly. So, `+=` operator takes care of typecasting.

Comment: No when you do `s+=x;` it does `s = (short) (s+x);`

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't say anything about the difference because there is none from the programmer's point of view. The

```
b = c + a;
```

notation exists because it is the normal case of an addition. The short form

```
b += a;
```

exists for the special case that `c` "is" `b` and really expands to

```
b = b + a;
```

Comment: Note that, as an example, if b is a `byte` and a is an `int`. `b = b+a;` won't compile but `b+=a;` will compile because it's equivalent to `b = (byte)(b+a);`. There is always an implicit cast when you use a compound operator. Here in this case, `b+=a` is equivalent to `(int)(b+a);` and not `b = b+a;`

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that in the first case, a temporary object `c = (a + b)` is created, then assigned back to `b`. In the second case, the operation happens in place and should be more efficient.

At least, this used to be in old C++: modern compilers and JIT will automatically detect and optimize this, so, actually, there is no difference at all.

Answer (score 1):

One is shorter, that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no difference at all in both the statements.

`b += a` internally will be treated as `b = b + a` only.

Answer (score 0):

There's basically no difference. The `+=` is only for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

`Add AND assignment` operator, It adds right operand to the left operand and assign the result to left operand  `B += A` is equivalent to `B = B + A`

Answer (score 0):

So far i only found a difference with the logical compound operators:

```
boolean accepted = firstCheck();

version 1: accepted = accepted && secondCheck();
version 2: accepted &= secondCheck();
```

the above code will behave differently:

version 1 will omit calling `secondCheck()` if accepted is false

version 2 will always call `secondCheck()`

Answer (score 0):

Theres is no difference between them hidden on lower level.
`b += a` is equivalent to `b = b + a`. 
However, there's some danger in here. It may seem that `b += a` is an atomic operation, however it first reads `b`, then reads `a`, then sums them, and then writes the result to `b`. Treating it as an atomic operation may cause errors when dealing with concurrent operations. In other words, always rememeber to provide some explicit lock when using this shorter `+=` operator in concurrent environment.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to ask yourself the same question would be, *What is the difference between `java.lang.String` and just `String`*? The difference is *huge* in terms of what source code is all about: expressiveness and readability.

Comment: You are not right! You can read first answer, posted by @RahulBobhate.