# what is the difference between a = a + b and a += b?

Tags: java

I know that both this statements evaluate to same answer but 
 is there any performance issue related to this statements?

Comment: Nothing, a+=1 will be converted as a = a+1 internally by compiler, I guess.

Comment: Look at the generated code.

Comment: The only difference is if `a` is an expression that has side-effects when evaluated. In the former case it gets evaluated (has side-effects) twice, in the latter case only once. If it is just a simple variable name for example they are identical 100%.

Comment: How they are written.

Comment: @Patashu: I don't believe there is any possible expression for `a` which would behave that way in Java.

Comment: Was wonderful to see downvotes without understanding the context, even after the comments

Comment: NB: The question used to read `a=a+i`; I've converted the `i` to `b` for readability.

Comment: When i was giving interview, that fellow said that there is performance point. a=a+i requires three fetches from memory and a+=i requires only two.  how's that?

Comment: There is a difference because the 1 is automatically assumed to be of the proper type to be added to a when += 1 is used. Saying a = a + 1 can cause a type casting error sometimes when += 1 would not.

Answer (score 0):

The generated code will be the same for both. The only difference is to the readability of the code.

Comment: Just to point out this is not exactly the case, [here's one of the highest voted java questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator).