# Java: Why doesn't (int) += (double) cause a "incompatible types" error?

Tags: java, type-conversion

Here's an oddity:

```
float a = 0;
a = a + Math.PI; // ERROR
```

and yet:

```
a += Math.PI; // OK!
```

even this works:

```
int b = 0;
b += Math.PI; // OK, too!
```

Why does the `+=` operator allow lossy implicit type conversions?

Comment: I have read this one on SO before but sadly I cant find the answer for you right away.  If its not answered when I come back I will search a bit more for you.

Comment: Weird but yes, this is a known fact to me. I think I've met it in a preparation book about SCJP or in some other book. This is a known peculiarity, maybe that's what the language specification says.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator

Comment: If arshajii's answer (or mine, if you really think so) correctly and satisfactorily answers your question, can you please "accept" it? If neither of the answers are satisfactory, I would suggest adding a bounty to the question.

Answer (score 16):

From [JLS §15.26.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

Notice that there is a cast involved with the compound assignment. However, with the simple addition there is no cast, hence the error.

If we include the cast, the error is averted:

```
float a = 0;
a = (float) (a + Math.PI);  // works
```

It's a common misconception that `x += y` is identical to `x = x + y`.

Comment: I see. A corollary question: why did the designers think it was a good idea when everywhere else Java is strongly typed?

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky It's hard to say. I suppose it's because you might sometimes want to increment numeric primitives by something of a different type (e.g. a float by a double, as you have).

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky: "Why did X design Y this way" is not a question that can usefully be answered on SO (unless the designer happens to be around).

Comment: "sometimes want to" is usually not a motivating factor for Java designers (thank goodness).

Comment: Think you want to increment a byte value by a certain offset. There was not literal for a byte ti Java 7. Requiring an explicit cast would have made such code quite verbose.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky It's impossible for me to give a more concrete answer to your comment.

Comment: @arshajii I think I got it. It's because `byte + byte` is always actually an `int`, so if `a += b` were simply `a = a + b`, then either `+=` couldn't ever be used with byte, short, and char, or the rules surrounding all this would need to become more complex. And Java designers hate complex rules.

Answer (score 2):

That's because

```
float a = 0;
double b = 1;
a += b;
```

is the equivalent of

```
float a = 0;
double b = 1;
a = (float)(a + b);
```

`a +=` is the same as `a = (<type of a>)(a +`