# Please explain Java's += and != operators

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. Please explain the `+=` and `!=` operators. I can't find where they're documented. I'd like a site that explains them.

Comment: _Oddly I can't find it documented anywhere_ What did you try looking up?

Comment: your title says += and question shows =!?

Comment: Gee. "java operators" on Google somehow, after great difficulty, managed to bring up http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html as the VERY FIRST result...

Comment: You probably mean `!=` instead of `=!`. The former is in the same style as `+=`, the latter is just an assignment of the inverse value.

Comment: Mark, I already went through that and it doesn't explain it.

Comment: Forgive me for my stupidity... I'm just trying to learn instead of cut and paste... I'll look at the related.

Comment: @Marc B, can you show where it is explained in the link you provided?

Comment: @dansalmo In the table, it's under assignment operator. In the links to the left, there's an article on assignment operators.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, still no explanation.  Can you find one?

Comment: @dansalmo `You can also combine the arithmetic operators with the simple assignment operator to create compound assignments. For example, x+=1; and x=x+1; both increment the value of x by 1.`

Comment: @dansalmo: search the page. It'll show up. Perhaps it's better to force the OP to **THINK** a bit for themselves and actually do a bit of **READING**. If all we do here is spoon feed pablum to the educationally ignorant, we'll just keep getting flooded with utterly trivial silly questions like this.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta hey it was not for you it was for Op Sorry

Comment: Sorry. I can see dansalmo's point. I can delete the question if necessary. Sorry for the edits. I'm not a very good/accustomed member yet...

Comment: So the answer was not on the page you linked to, it was buried in another page.  You should stick to helping people that already know the answers to the questions they are asking.  The java docs suck.  This OP's question and the answers below will help 1000's of others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+=` operator works as so:

```
int x;
x += 3;
//Expands into: x = x + 3;
```

!= is just Logical NOT Equal To:

```
5 != 6 //True
5 != 5 //False
```

Answer (score 2):

For this `+=` see the link provided in the comment of @cristian [Java's +=, -=, *=, /= compound assignment operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator?rq=1)

To explain =!
I am giving example

```
boolean a=true;
boolean b=true;
System.out.println(a=!b);
```

It will print `false`

**reason**

`b` is `true`,`!` of `b` means false and you are assigning `a` with `false`

**The original post was** `=!` and not its has been changed to `!=`

`!=` means `not equal to` If you want to compare whether 2 are same or not then we use `!=`

**Example**

```
int i=1;int j=2;
if(i!=j)
{
System.out.println("not equals");
}
```

**output**not equals

Comment: So `=!` is two operators?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry didnt understand you

Comment: You should make it clearer that `=!` is a combination of two operators: the assignment operator and the unary negation operator.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ohho now I understand.I thought that my answer is wrong so you asking me something

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The original post was =! and now it has been changed to !=

Comment: Meh, just explain both if you want to.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes done

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you have experience in web apps?

Comment: Sure, I've got a bit of exp.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44994/discussion-between-jquerylearner-and-sotirios-delimanolis)