# Java typecasting confusion

Tags: java, casting

Take these two snippet for example:

**Case 1:**

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = s.nextInt(); /** take user input **/

n *= Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
```

and

**Case 2:**

```
int k=10;
double kk = 10.10;

int rst = k*kk;
```

In both the cases, I am not doing any typecasting from my side, but *Case 1* executes and prints value of `n` correctly but *Case 2* throws an error, `can not convert from double to int`. Why this difference?

Comment: Because `*=` (and `+=` and it's kin) is computed in the type of the left argument.  However `*` "promotes" the arguments to the type of the "widest" argument.

Comment: Because `n *= Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` is `n = (int)(n * Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator?rq=1

Comment: @exception1 : your link pretty much solves my doubt...thankx!!! :)

Comment: **voting to close as duplicate of thread given by user @exception**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first works and the second doesn't because the `*=` `+=` `-=` etc **add an automatic cast**.

If, for example, you were to change your second example to;

```
int k=10;
double kk = 10.10;
k*= kk;
```

It should work. Alternatively you could just add an *explicit* cast like so `rst = (int)(k*kk);`

Answer (score 1):

> The arithmetic promotion in Java happens when you apply an arithmetic
>   operation on two variables with different data-types. In this case the
>   compiler will convert the data type of one operand in the binary
>   arithmetic operation to the type of the other operand.

In your case, for multiplying an int and a double, the int is promoted to double, and the result is double. So, it can't be stored into an int.

See more at: http://www.codemiles.com/java/arithmetic-promotion-t3487.html#sthash.sdHtt7pG.dpuf

Answer (score 0):

The result of the multiplication of an integer (`int`) and a floating point in java will always result in a floating point (`double`). You are assigning this result to the integer `rst` which requires casting.

Comment: isn't the same thing happening in `case 1` too??? multiplication value is getting assigned back to `int`??

Comment: @NoobEditor - Yes, quite right.