# Does does the java-o-o extension support the "+=" operator?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, operator-overloading

Simple question but if it does then what is its equivalent verbal function name(that is substituted by +=)?

**Edit:**
By "java-o-o" I mean the [java-o-o](http://amelentev.github.io/java-oo/) **(Java-operator-overloading)** plugin (hack) for java.

Any insight will be helpful!

Comment: possible duplicate of [java += operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator)

Comment: There is no operator which is equivalent to `+=`  The compiler replaces `a += b;` with something like `a = a + b;`

Comment: @sankrish I am referring to the [java-o-o](http://amelentev.github.io/java-oo/) (operator overloading plugin not Java Object Oriented) that uses a lambda expression hack to allow C++ like operator overloading in Java.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't understand how it is relevant here since the plugin primarily uses lambda expressions that effectively substitute method names allowing programmers the use of pseudo operator overloading *If I used the right wording*

Comment: @reubenjohn It wasn't clear to me that you were using a preprocessor addon. It is not one of the listed operators.  I suggest you ask the developers via github whether this is supported or planned, if they don't know, no-one does.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Apologies if my question wasn't informative enough

Comment: @reubenjohn No problem, don't be surprised when people answer what they think the question was. sometimes they answer without reading carefully, so if you are doing something different you have to make it really obvious.