# Computer Operator Confusion

Tags: java

Here is code from Java champs.

```
class Compound
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int k = 12;
        k /= --k;
        System.out.println(k);
        k *= k++;
        System.out.println(k);
        k *= ++k;
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

The options given are

- 1    It will compile successfully and display 1 followed by 2 and then 3
  as an output.
- 2    It will compile successfully and display 1 followed by 1 and then 2
  as an output.
- 3    It will compile successfully and display 1 followed by 3 and then 4
  as an output.
- 4    It will generate compile time error.

The output is option-2. Can someone explain, how come it evaluates to option-2?

Comment: Take it one step at a time. `12 / 11` is `1.09`, which is 1 when casted to int. Thats why `1` prints for the first statement. Do the rest of the calculations, and youll get your answer. `num++` will increase number and return the previous value (so the value it was at before incremenating), while `++num` returns the incremeanted value

Comment: Use a pen and paper. Work it out. Or step through it with a debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things you need to know:

- `k(operator)=value` is basically `k=k(operator)value` (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator)).
- `++` is incrementation `--` is decrementation. There exists pre, and post versions of this operators where:

  - `x++` (post-incrementation) will first return current value of `x` then will increment `x` (if `x=2` `print(x++)` would first pass `2` to method then increment `x` to become `3`)
  - `++x` (pre-incrementation) will first increment value of `x` then will return it
- `++` `--` have higher precedence than `*` `/` and these have higher precedence than `=`
- dividing integers will also return integer so `7/3` will become `2` not `2.33333...`
- in `argument1 (operator) argument2 (operator) argument3` `argument1` will be evaluated before `argument2`, and `argument2` will be evaluated before `argument3` (in other words they are evaluated from left to right)
- `variable = expression` before putting value of `expression` into `variable` it will need to be evaluated first, so `x=x+1` first `x+1` expression will need be calculated, then `x` can be set with result of this evaluation.

so you can rewrite your code as

`k/=--k;` -> `k = k / --k;` -> `k = (k / (--k))`
`k*=k++;` -> `k = k * k++;` -> `k = (k * (k++))`
`k*=++k;` -> `k = k * ++k;` -> `k = (k * (++k))`

So at start with `k=12`.

`k = (k  / (--k))`
`k = (12  / (--k))` lets replace first `k` with its current value
`k = (12 / 11)` pre-decrement `--k` will first decrement `k` to `11`, then return decremented value
`k = 1` because we are dividing integers `12/11` result is `1` not `1.0909...`

So now `k=1`. Time for `k*=k++;`

`k = (k * (k++))`
`k = (1 * (k++))`
`k = (1 * (1))` post-increment `k++` first returns current value of `k` which is `1` then increments it
`k = 1`  `1*1=1`, nothing special here

So `k` is still `1`. Time for `k*=++k;`

`k = (k * (++k))`
`k = (1 * (++k))` since `k=1` 
`k = (1 * (2))` `++k` first increments then returns value, so `k` becomes `2` and this value is returned
`k = 2`  `1*2 = 2` nothing special here.

Comment: thanks so much. It helped me clarify the concepts. Though i have a question, when previous value is returned, where does temporary incremented value gets stored ?

Comment: I assume that you are asking about `x++`. It mostly works like this: current value of `x` is passed to processor (or in case of `print(x++)` to local variable of `print` which is separate than used `x`) and new (incremented) value is stored in `x` variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
int k=12;
k/=--k;

//i.e. k=k/--k; i.e. k=12/11; i.e k=1

System.out.println(k);
k*=k++;

/*i.e. k=k*k++; i.e. k=1*1; and after this statement value of k is still 1,
  inspite of k++,

  since postfix version increase k by 1 after evaluation of k*k++, 
  but just after that 1 is assigned to k overwriting its previous value.

*/

System.out.println(k);

k*=++k;
//i.e. k=k*(++k); i.e. k=1*2;

System.out.println(k);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int k = 12;
k /= --k;
System.out.println(k);
k *= k++;
System.out.println(k);
k *= ++k;
System.out.println(k);
```

The first equation is `12 / 11`. `--k` will decrease `k`, and return the decreased value (which is `11`). `12 / 11` is `1.09`. When casted to int (happens implcitly), the decimal places are omited, and you're left with `1`. The `1` gets printed to the console.

The second equation is `1 * 1`. `k++` incremeants `k`, then returns the previous value (the value it was before the incremeant, so `1`). `1` gets printed to the console; now you know why you have the first two 1s printing out.

The final equation is `1 * 2`. By now, you should know how incremeanting works. The answer is printed to the cosole. Thats why the answer is option #2