# Compilation error for the same statement?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

When this code is executed, I get a compile time error -

```
byte b = 50;
b = b * 2;
```

Error -

> incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to bye

I am aware of the fact that Java **automatically promotes byte to int** during compilation.

Then why does the following code doesn't produce any error and runs fine -

```
byte b = 50;
b *= 2;
```

Isn't `b = b * 2` and `b *= 2` the same?

Comment: Nope, read up on the combo operators. Also, this is a dupe, but I can't search for it now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator

Comment: If you get a compile-time error the code isn't being executed.