# What is: fact *= i;

Tags: java, while-loop, bufferedreader

Why is this statement used: `fact*=i;`.  I can't understand because I am a beginner.  Is there some other way that we can write the same statement in a while loop?

```
//This is my program for factorial using input from user.

import java.io.*;

public class factorialInput {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int i = 1;
        int fact = 1;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter any number:");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        while (i <= n) {
            fact *= i;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("Factorial of" + n + "!" + "=" + fact);
    }
}
```

Comment: `fact = fact * i`, it's short hand, programmers are lazy ;)

Comment: This question is in no way a duplicate of "Using loops to compute factorial numbers, Java".  `*=` is a "Compound Assignment Operator".  Search using that name to find lots of explanations.

Comment: @CandiedOrange +1 I agree with you. Maybe quite interesting for meta the fact that there are so many questions beeing closed with a wrong marking for duplicate...

Comment: I flagged it hoping I wouldn't have to take it that far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator is not exactly a duplicate of this question either but it gives some deeper understanding.

Answer (score 2):

`fact*=i;` is equivalent to `fact = fact * i;`

From [tutorialpoints](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm)

*= is multiply AND assignment operator, It multiplies right operand with the left operand and assign the result to left operand