# Java Puzzler - casting a double to int

Tags: java

```
int anInt = 1;
double aDouble = 2.5;

anInt = anInt + aDouble; // Error - need to cast double to int

anInt += aDouble; // This is ok. Why?

anInt = aDouble; // This is also an error.

anInt = 1 + aDouble; // This is also an error.
```

So my questions is: Why is it not a compile error to do `anInt += aDouble`?

Comment: Can you explain what do you need?

Comment: @Gunaseelan isnt it in the code in the comments?

Comment: @Gunaseelan i guess he is asking why the `int  = int + double` does throw an error while `int += double` doesn´t

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java += operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator)

Comment: Hate interview questions: their relation to practice is zero to none.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three of the four cases properly report an error. Compound assignment is the only exception from the rule. Java Language Specification, part 15.26.2, explains why:

> **15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators**
>
> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1
>   = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.
>
> For example, the following code is correct:
>
> ```
> short x = 3;
> x += 4.6;
> ```
>
> and results in x having the value 7 because it is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> short x = 3;
> x = (short)(x + 4.6);
> ```

As you can see, the error is avoided by implicit insertion of a cast.

Comment: Yes. I came across it in my code and was just surprised the compound assignment didn't need a cast.  Thanks for the answer.