# Need help explaining a concept to students

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I teach Computer Science AP and we use java to teach programming concepts.  One thing my students and I have noticed is that the following code gives a Loss of precision error:

```
int j = 0;
j = j + 4.0;
```

however this code does not:

```
int j = 0
j += 4.0;
```

To me, these are the same thing.  I have searched for some posting to answer this but could not find anything  If you have a link to a post that explains this, my students and I would appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator).

Comment: This might help [Java += operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator)

Comment: If you teach CS, you may be interested in the new [CS Educator's Stack Exchange](http://cseducators.stackexchange.com) (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter [through here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the expression:

```
j += 4.0;
```

is equivalent to:

```
j = (int) (j + 4.0);
```

Check [JLS § 15.16.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1
>   is evaluated only once.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `+=` is a [**Compound Assignment Operator**](http://java.about.com/od/c/g/compoundassgnment.htm), which makes an implicit cast required to not throw the error. Without it, you are adding two different primitive data types *without* any implicit or explicit cast. Essentially, the `+=` technique is equivalent to :

```
j = (int)(j + 4.0);
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator) may further explain the `+=` operator to you and your students.

Answer (score 0):

```
j+=4.0
```

Is the same as

```
j = j + (int)4.0
```

So the compiler automatically adds the cast for you in that situation. In the first example, it does not.