# Simple short addition yields warning

Tags: java, eclipse, lint

I found some questions concerning `short` arithmetic but none of them compared the following three cases. I wonder why these two pieces of code are ok

(a)

```
            short m = 1;
            m += m;
```

(b)

```
            short m = 1;
            m += m + m;
```

while this

(c)

```
            short m = 1;
            m = m + m;
```

leads to the error *"Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to short"* ?

Comment: Related, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator

Comment: Something fun (not really related to the question) that I once found: If we have `String s = null`, it will turn into `"null"` if you do `s += ""`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a warning - it's an error.

There are two facts at work here:

- There's no `short + short` operator; the "smallest" addition is `int + int`, with a result type of `int`, and the operands are automatically promoted to `int` if necessary (see [JLS 15.18.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2))
- Compound assignment operators always have an implicit cast (see [JLS 15.26.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2))

The second point is why the first two operations work. You've effectively got:

```
m = (short) (m + m);
```

And

```
m = (short) (m + m + m);
```

The first point is why the last operation doesn't work - the type of `m + m` is `int`, and you can't assign an `int` value to a `short` variable. (You need a cast...)