# Cannot convert from long to int error only occurs when using simple assignment

Tags: java

Java is doing something here that I don't understand. If I have

```
int sum = 0;
long num = 1234;
```

Using the assignment operator += will work fine

```
sum += num % 10;
```

However, using simple assignment will cause a "Cannot convert long to int" error

```
sum = sum + num % 10;
```

Why is this ??

Comment: This is maybe the better (or at least the more common) duplicate: [Java += operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator).

Answer (score 2):

When you do += that's a compound assignment and compiler internally have some mechanism to evaluate it. Where as in first case the compiler given an error since it normal statement.

JSL on how it treats compound assignment.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2

In your first case, compiler translate your code to

```
sum += (int) (num % 10);
```

So there is a cast internally by compiler. Hence you are not prompted to an error. Compiler doing your job there :)

Comment: Thanks Suresh. Makes sense the internal cast