# += Operator in C++

Tags: c++, operators

Someone please tell me the difference between the following codes which add two variables of datatype `int`. I want to know which one is better.

**Code A:**

```
sum = sum + value;
```

**Code B:**

```
sum += value;
```

We usually prefer `++` operator over `+= 1`. Is there any specific reason behind that as well ?

**I want to know the difference between the above codes with respect to the conventions or efficiency level. Which one is recommended ?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While the end result of the e.g. `someVar++` operator is the same as `someVar += 1` there are other things playing in as well.

Lets take a simple statement like

```
foo = bar++;
```

It's actually equivalent (but not equal) to

```
temp = bar;
bar += 1;
foo = temp;
```

As for the prefix and suffix increment or decrement operators, they have different [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), which will affect things like *pointer arithmetic* using those operators.

---

As for the difference between

```
foo += 1;
```

and

```
foo = foo + 1;
```

there's no different for primitive types (like `int` or `float`) or pointer types, but there's a very big difference if `foo` is an object with operator overloading. Then

```
foo += 1;
```

is equal to

```
foo.operator+=(1);
```

while

```
foo = foo + 1;
```

is equal to

```
temp = foo.operator+(1);
foo.operator=(temp);
```

Semantically a very big difference. Practically too, especially if any of the operator overload functions have side-effects, or if the copy-constructor or destructor have some side-effects (or you forget [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)).

Answer (score 14):

One calls operators `=` and `+` the later calls operator `+=`.

operators `++` and `+=` are preferred because of readability - most programmers know what they mean.

On the other hand most modern compilers will generate the same code for `+= 1` as `++` and `+`/`=` as `+=` for builtin types;

But for user defined `class`s, the actual operators will be called and it's up to the implementer of those `class`s to make sense of it all.  In these cases `++` and `+=` can be optimal.

Comment: but in my case both do the same at the end. which method would you recommend ?

Comment: @ItbanSaeed Your original post did not mention what types `sum` and `value` are.  That's why there is no concrete answer as to what is recommended.  If they are user-defined types and `+` or `+=` are overloaded, then it's up to you to decide what is efficient by looking at the source for these overloads and doing tests.  And no, doing a `+1` does not determine if those are `ints`.  Someone could easily come up with a `big_int` class that takes an `int` as a parameter in the overloaded `+` or `+=`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am sorry for the misunderstanding. Thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score 7):

`cout << sum++;` Would print out the value of sum before it was incremented. Also, depending on what you are doing, you can overwrite the operators `+=` and `+`.

Comment: I am concerned with the specific statements I mentioned in my code. **Which one would you recommend and why ?**

Comment: I could suggest code B for readability. As for ++ vs +=1, I would prefer ++ again for readability.

Answer (score 6):

When you minimize code, you reduce the chance of an error (a typographical error or a logical error).

By using

```
sum += value;
```

you reduce the chance - ever so slightly - of an error while typing

```
sum = sum + value;
```

The same with `value++;`

```
value += 1;
```

could be more easily confused with

`value += l;`  where l is a variable....

Its more about consistency that it is about right or wrong, but reducing code is a major bonus for maintainability.

Care must be taken with precendence of operators however, in complex statements.

Answer (score 5):

In the case shown there's no particular reason to prefer one method of incrementing the value over another except perhaps for readability purposes. In this case I think I'd prefer `sum += value` over `sum = sum + value` as it's a bit briefer and (I think) clearer, but YMMV on that.

As far as prefering `++` over `+= 1`, (IMO again) `++` is preferable when incrementing a value as part of an expression, e.g. `sum += array[index++]` - but if the entire point of what's being done is adding one to a value I'd prefer `index += 1`. But let's face it, a great deal of this is personal preference and spur-of-the-moment choice. I always try to write what I think, at that moment, is the simplest and clearest code possible - but I must admit that when I go back and read some of my own code later I have more "What was I thinkin'?!?" moments than I'd care to admit to. :-)

YMMV.

Best of luck.

Comment: thanks for this nice explanation, but in my opinion `sum = sum + value` looks more readable instead of `sum += value` so why should I use `sum += value` moreover, **can you please relate it with efficiency or standard conventions ?** I agree that one should write what he thinks but let us suppose that we have to justify each and every statement of our code so how would you justify `sum += value` since (IMO) it less readable than `sum = sum + value`.

Comment: @ItbanSaeed operator `+=` for a *well-written* user defined type is more efficient than using `operator +`.  The reason is that `+` creates a brand new object, while `+=` works with the existing object.  But note -- *well written*.

Comment: @ItbanSaeed - I agree with what PaulMcKenzie wrote in his comment regarding the C++ issues surrounding user-written types/classes. To my eye `sum += value` is easier to read because there's fewer tokens to (mentally) parse - but again, that's a matter of personal preference and habit. If justification is needed, my "justification" is that, for me, it's easier and quicker to comprehend than `sum = sum + value` - but then, I've been writing C and it's derivatives for over 30 years (my, where *does* the time go? :-) so perhaps it's just that my habits have pretty much atrophied. Again - YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

Code A and B do the same thing. The advantage to using Code B is that it's quicker to type and easier to read.

As for using the `++` operator over `+= 1`, again it is for readability. Although there is a difference between `foo++` and `++foo`. The former is read first and then incremented, while the latter is incremented first and then read from.

Comment: See my comments.  It cannot be determined if `A` and `B` do the same thing unless we know exactly what types are being used.

Answer (score 2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent
>   to `E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1`
>   is evaluated only once.

An example cited from [Java's +=, -=, *=, /= compound assignment operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator)

[...] the following code is correct:

```
short x = 3;
x += 4.6;
```

and results in x having the value 7 because it is equivalent to:

```
short x = 3;
x = (short)(x + 4.6);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its basically the same thing. Its both an operator.

One of it calls `=` and `+`. And the other `+=`..

So if you did value +=5. Value goes up by 5. += is better and more organized. And shortens your code whitch is better and more professional.

Comment: The OP did not specify what types `sum` and `value` are.  So yes, semantically it means "add", but nothing stops an overload of `+` and `+=` from doing something totally inefficient or unorthodox.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the two in terms of functionality. A += B actually means A = A + B. The first one is just a shorter way of writing the second.

Comment: Just to repeat my other comments -- we don't have enough information to determine if there is a difference or not in functionality.  It all depends on what `A` and `B` are and if those operators are overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

They both are same up to that, both can be used for incrementing the value of a variable (stored in it).

`x++` will increment the value of `x` by one (1) every run time.

`+=` adds right operand to the left operand and stores the result in left operand.
Something like following:
`C += A` is just same as `C = C + A`

The difference between both `++` and `+=` is that the first can increment by one (1) only, while `+=` can be used to increment more than one in just one line.

e.g:

```
x += 1; // will increment by 1 every run time
x += 4; // will increment by 4 every run time
x += 10; // will increment by 10 every run time
```