# Difference between assignments operator (+= and =)

Tags: c++

I have been programming c++ for a while now. My question might still be naive though. :)

What is the difference between += and +. For e.g.

```
std::string a = "Hi";
a += "b" + "c";
```

OR

```
std::string a = "Hi";
a = a + "b" + "c";
```

If there is any difference, which one is more optimized to use? Which one have less operations count?

Comment: compiler should handle optimization

Comment: I believe the original C used a different assembly instruction for += which was more optimized. Now it doesn't make a lot of difference; the compiler will optimize it for you.

Comment: Mind you because there is no `string` involved in `a += "b" + "c";`'s addition of  `"b" + "c"` the compiler'll probably get upset.

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465848/operator-in-c

Comment: @Satarakar I'd say yes, except user4581301 might have a point about std::string: It might be slightly different. Otherwise, yes, it's a dupe.

Comment: Looks like in the trivial case of `int`s there can be a subtle difference. How much it costs is something I'd have to profile.

Answer (score 9):

In this specific example, there's a big difference: `a += "b" + "c";` doesn't compile, while `a = a + "b" + "c";` does. The former attempts to add two pointers, which is syntactically invalid. The latter adds a `std::string` and a `char*` pointer, and there happens to be a suitable `operator+` overload for that.