# Can someone please tell me why I am facing this issue on GeeksforGeeks code editor on 30 Day of Code Challenge?

Tags: c++, stack

If I write this

```cpp
ans += st.top().first;
```

my program runs fine but if I replace it with this

```cpp
ans = ans + st.top().first;
```

which is one at same it comes time limit exceeded. Can someone please tell me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [+= Operator in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465848/operator-in-c)

Comment: @myeongkilkim No, I am getting the error of time limit exceeded so that question does not answer to my problem

Comment: Search the difference in `operator+=` and `operator+` code that is called in these lines. You can find the called operators by stepping into them while debugging this code.

Comment: Is `ans` a variable you defined, or some magic specific to the challenge evaluator?