# Compile Error in Java add char to int

Tags: java

```
char c = 'c';
int x = 10;
```

Here is my problem: when I write     c = c+x; I have an error and the solution is casting     c = (char) (c+x);
but when I write c+=x; without casting I have no error.

And the output after
    `c = (char) (c+x);
    System.out.println(c+x);`
is m 
but the output after `System.out.println(c+x);` is 119

What difference between    c+=x; and    c = c + x; in java

Comment: What is your expected output? `c10`?

Comment: "And the output after  c = (char) (c+x); System.out.println(c+x); is m" No, it's not - it would be 129. The output of `System.out.println(c)` would be `m`.

Comment: [Java +=, -=, *=, /= operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operators)

Answer (score 2):

The type of `c + x` is `int`, so you can't assign it back to a `char`.

`System.out.println((char) (c + x))` invokes the `PrintStream.println(char)` overload, so it prints as a `char`.

`System.out.println(c + x)` invokes the `PrintStream.println(int)` overload, so it prints as an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

It's just how compound assignment operators like `+=` are defined.

See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1

In your case the type of `c` is `char`, so the cast to a `char` is implicit when you write `c+=x`.