# why post increment in char is working but explicit adding is not working

Tags: java, casting, char

This code is working-

```
public class charTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char ch1= 'Y';

        System.out.println(ch1);
        ch1++;
        System.out.println(ch1);
    }
}
```

But why the below code is not working?

```
public class charTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    char ch1= 'Y';

        System.out.println(ch1);

        ch1=ch1+1;
        System.out.println(ch1);
    }
}
```

Isn't `ch1++` and `ch1+1` supposed to be the same thing?

Comment: See also [Java's +=, -=, *=, /= compound assignment operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/javas-compound-assignment-operators)

Comment: Thank you ... shmosel that solved my problem :)