# Why does num+=array[i] works differently to num=num+array[i] in for loop

Tags: java

I have code

```
public class NumArray {
    int[] instanceNums;
    public NumArray(int[] nums) {
        this.instanceNums=nums;
    }

    public int sumRange(int i, int j) {
        if(i<0||j>instanceNums.length-1||instanceNums.length==0||instanceNums==null) return 0;
        int res=0;
        for(int index=i;index<=j;index++){
           res=res+instanceNums[index];
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

I found that in the for loop, the answer would be incorrect if I used

```
res+=instanceNums[index];
```

Why? Thanks

Comment: I see no reason it would be different.

Comment: I don't believe you, for what `array`, `i` and `j` values?

Comment: Ah forgive my stupid eye, I realized I put res=+instanceNumbs[index] @JamesKPolk

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yeah it is actually same, I made a typo in the code

Comment: just a side note: the line `if(i<0||j>instanceNums.length-1||instanceNums.length==0||instanceNums==null) return 0;` will be in trouble in case of `instanceNums=null`, because it will try to access `instanceNums.length` this part before checking if its null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **won't** notice any difference between your two ways of adding values, because an expression using the `+=` assignment operator, such as

```
x += y
```

is equivalent to

```
x = x + y
```

This is what Oracle state. Let's prove this theory. Consider this class:

```
class Analysis {
    public static void add(int x, int y) {
        x = x + y;
    }
}
```

After having decompiled the bytecode using `javap`, you can see the following result:

```
  public static void add(int, int);
    Code:
       0: iload_0
       1: iload_1
       2: iadd
       3: istore_0
       4: return
```

If you replace the definition of the static method `add` with `X += y`, the Java compiler build the same bytecode.

---

Regarding your last comment, the assignment operator `+=` is different from `=+`, as the second is the simplest form of assignment `=` followed by the plus (`+`) sign.

Comment: Nitpicker here, `x+=y` is actually equivalent to `x = (type of x)(x+y)`, though in this case that indeed makes no difference.

Comment: @biziclop Wouldn't it be redundant to indicate your equivalence given the result is all the cases stored in `x` (of type `x`)?

Comment: In this case, because both `x` and `y` are `int`s, it would be. But [in general](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/javas-compound-assignment-operators), no.

Comment: Even if the type of `y` is different, the result of the sum is stored in `x`, which shares the same type of the first operand, as the first operand is `x`.

Comment: Yes, except if `y` is a `long`, the type of `x+y` is a `long` too. It doesn't matter whether `x` is the first operand or not, the numeric promotion to `long` will happen. To then store the `long` result in `x`, which is of type `int` would require a narrowing primitive conversion, which doesn't happen implicitly. Hence the explicit cast.