# On Chars in java we can apply prefix and postfix modes but not able to perform char = char+1

Tags: java

In below program we are able perform operation ch1++ but not able to perform ch1=ch1+1

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    char ch1 = 88;
    System.out.println("Ch1 is " + ch1);

    ch1=ch1+1;
    ch1++;
    System.out.println("ch1 is "+ch1);
}
```

Comment: There's a similar question _somewhere_ on SO, but I can't find it. :) The upshot is that two things are happening here. First is that `ch1 + 1` is an int type (not char) and ints can't be implicitly cast to chars -- you have to provide a char. The second is that `x++` isn't actually equivalent to `x = x + 1`, but rather `x = (T) (x + 1)` where T is x's type. In other words, `ch1++` adds the cast that `ch1 + 1` does not, and which is needed.

Comment: use this  ch1=(char) (ch1+1);

Comment: thanks for the explanation

Comment: This may provide some insight: [Java's +=, -=, *=, /= compound assignment operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/javas-compound-assignment-operators). A similar process is used with pre/post increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ch1+1` has type integer, you need to cast it to char, like that:

```
(char)(ch1+1)
```

in more details:

java see two values, one type char, one type integer (1 is integer), to perform `+` operation java needs both arguments be the same, the safest way is to promote `char` to `int`, this is why result is `int`

`ch1++` is different one, java treats this construct as:

```
ch1 = (char)(ch1+1)
```

so, cast is added automatically

Answer (score 1):

According to the Java Spec,

> [The type of an additive expression on numeric operands is the *promoted type* of its operands.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2)

whereas

> the type of the [prefix](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1) and [postfix](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) increment expression is the *type* of the variable... Before the addition, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is performed on the value 1 and the value of the variable. If necessary, *the sum is narrowed by a narrowing primitive conversion* (§5.1.3) and/or subjected to boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to the type of the variable before it is stored.

(emphasis added)

So using `+` first applies a [Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) to the operands, turning them into integers, and then maintains that promoted type as the expression's result. `++` also applies promotion, but it also adds a narrowing step afterward so that the result type is the same as the original variable's type.

This behavior makes sense, because you know that a `++` is changing the value of the original parameter, whereas the result of a `+` operation could be saved into some other value:

```
int i = Character.MAX_VALUE + 1;
```

As the other answers point out, if you want to save the result of some addition back into a character variable, the integer result of a `+` operation will need to be cast back down to a `char`, like this:

```
ch1 = (char)(ch1+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast ch + 1 to a (char), as the result of 1 + ch1 is an int

```
ch1=(char)ch1+1;
```

Comment: yes i can do it that way but my question is isnt ch1++ and ch1=ch1+1 both same ??

Comment: `ch1++` and `ch1+1` are not the same because 1 is an `int`, and an integer plus a char is a (4 byte) `int`, as opposed to a 2 byte `char`

Comment: @AkashChavan technically, there is an implicit cast on the pre/post increments. Same with doing `ch1 += 1`. See: [Java's +=, -=, *=, /= compound assignment operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/javas-compound-assignment-operators)