# Can you explain this expression in java? --> sum += sum + d

Tags: java, for-loop, operators, operation

I got my sample exam question in java. I saw this expression `sum += sum + d` in the for loop.
Here is the code:

```
double sum =0;

for (double d = 0; d<10; sum += sum + d) {
    d += 0.1;
}
```

I just dont understand that part.
I only know these:

```
x+=1
x=x + ++x;
x=x + x++;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what part is confusing?

Comment: `sum += sum + d` is same as `sum = sum + sum + d` is same as `sum = sum * 2 + d`

Comment: @Andreas: Please put answers in the answers section. A short answer is not necessarily a poor one. Ditto Berger.

Comment: You understand `x+=1` and `x=x + ++x` but have difficulties with `sum += sum + d`? You'd probably better dive into the topic again otherwise it might hurt your exam.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java's +=, -=, \*=, /= compound assignment operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/javas-compound-assignment-operators)

Comment: @Thomas I will Thomas, I will. Thank you. I have started Java 3 months ago along with 3 other subjects. So it  was a bit diffucult to focus on all of them equally. So I am new to Java. Pulling my hair, when I stuck or don't understand something. However, I keep going. I wish I will be Soft.Engineer one day. CHeers !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

(I'm glad you understand the three obfuscated statements. But please don't use them in production. The final two are undefined in C and C++).

`sum += a` is shorthand for `sum = sum + a` for any `a` (neglecting any subtle differences due to implicit type conversions).

So `sum += sum + d` is `sum = sum + sum + d;` which simplifies to

`sum = 2 * sum + d;`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bathsheba.

Answer (score 1):

If to be more accurate, `sum += a` **is not** same to `sum = sum + a`, there is a type cast to type of sum. Let's consider the next example:

```
short x = 3;
x += 4.6;
```

It's the same to

```
short x = 3;
x = (short)(x + 4.6);
```

But not to `x = x + 4.6`
So, we have `type cast to the type of sum`. For more details read 
[JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1
>   is evaluated only once.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

From the [operators precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), you can see that `+` (additive) operator has higher precedence than `+=` (assignment) operator, so we first evaluate the `sum + d` part, let's call this result `sumplusd`, we get :

```
sum += sumplusd
```

Then we evaluate `+=`, that is increment the variable on the left part of the expression by the value on the right part, we get :

`sum = sum + sumplusd`, which reads `sum = sum + (sum + d)`, which reads `sum = sum*2 + d` .

Comment: Thanks Berger! I am surprised from fast answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since, `sum + = "any variable or constant"` is equivalent to `sum = sum + "variable or constant"`. Thus, `sum+=sum+d` would be same as `sum = sum + ( sum + d )`.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the **whole** mess, including the `do` loop:

```
double sum = 0.0;
double d = 0.0;
while ( d < 10.0 )
{
    sum = 2.0*sum + d
    d = d + 0.1;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't really answer OPs question. He is asking to explain something not re-write the code

Comment: I thought the re-write would be be explanation enough.

Comment: Thanks Jack! Yeah your code is much easy to read and understand.