# Java: Please explain the difference between these two statements

Tags: java, casting, byte

```
byte b;
b= b+10;
```

and

```
byte b;
b+=10;
```

The first instance gives an error while the second gives correct output can anyone explain the internal operation here

Comment: In Java, both these statements will produce a compilation error

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/why-dont-javas-compound-assignment-operators-require-casting

Comment: In Java, `byte b;` and then doing something with `b` before initializing it causes a compile error. Change `byte b;` in your examples to `byte b = 0;` to make them meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

**b += 10 means**

1. Find the place identified by x
2. Add 10 to it

**But b = b + 10 means:**

1. Find the place identified by b
2. Copy b into an accumulator
3. Add b to the accumulator
4. Store the result in b
5. Find the place identified by b
6. Copy the accumulator to it

Both the result will be the same but b+=10 will be preferred over b=b+10. You can find more detail here in this answer:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134118/why-are-shortcuts-like-x-y-considered-good-practice