# What is the difference? And does this matter in bigger loops?

Tags: java, performance, time

I was wondering if there is a complexity and time difference when doing these two operations:

1)

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    sum = sum + i;
}
```

2)

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    sum += i;
}
```

or maybe image the problem to be bigger numbers/data, this is just an example.

Comment: the difference is miniscule and you really should not bother with this at all. I think java even compiles `sum += i` down to `sum = sum + i`

Comment: Chances are both will compile to the same bytecode.

Comment: This is quite hard to verify in Java (in C you could compile the code and check the assembler). I conject that the same bytecode would be produced: effectively `++sum` which has been a native machine code instruction for donkeys years.

Comment: @Bathsheba you can check in Java as well with `javap`.

Comment: @Henry. Cool. What will they think of next?

Comment: Infact they compile to the same byte code.

Comment: Please look up **premature optimization**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These variants are the same from performance point of view (both will be as **iadd** instruction in java bytecode)

But `sum += 1` replaced with `sum = (int) (sum + 1)`
And it has differrens for types like `byte` or `short` for compilation
E.g. this code will be compiled

```
byte i = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    i += j; //i = (byte) (i + j)
}
```

but you will get compilation error for code

```
byte i = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    i = i + j;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in priority, compound assignment `sum += i` is less primary than assignment and addition `sum = i + 1`.
Incrementation `i++` is even more primary.

for more information : [operator precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/)

Comment: The priority seems irrelevant in the context of this question.

Comment: the more important thing than precedence is that [`+=` doesn't require a cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8710619/995714), but that's also irrelevant here