# Concatenation using the + and += operators in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, concatenation

Recently, I have noticed an inconsistency while concatenating lists.

So if I use the **+** operator, it doesn't concatenates list with any object of different type. For example,

```py
l = [1,2,3]
l = l + (4,5)        #TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
```

But, if I use the **+=** operator, it neglects the type of the object. For example,

```py
l = [1,2,3]
l += "he"            #Here, l becomes [1, 2, 3,"h", "e"]

l += (56, 67)        #Here, l becomes [1, 2, 3,"h", "e", 56, 67]
```

So, is it just the semantics of the language or some other reason?

Comment: If you're using `+` with operands of different types, there is ambiguity about what type you expect the result to be. With `+=`, it is implied that the left operand determines the type of the result.

Comment: `+=` for lists is *more or less* equivalent to `list.extend()`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The basic idea is that the `+` and the `+=` operators are not necessarily the same operation in Python, and they are indeed different for lists. The `+` operation is carried out by the `__add__` magic method while the `+=` operation is carried out by the `__iadd__` (in-place add) magic method. These magic methods come from the type on the left of the operator.

The in-place adding for a list does not require a list on the right-hand side, just an iterable. The items are then taken one-by-one from the iterable and appended to the list. This is similar to the list's `extend` method. So the `+=` operator does not *neglect* the type of the object on the right, it just *extends* the possible types that can be used.

This behavior is somewhat confusing--it must be since you are the second person in two days I have seen ask a similar (but not duplicate) question on this issue. However, this behavior is convenient--we now have an easy way to combine a list with any iterable.

For more on this, see [Why do Python lists let you += a tuple, when you can’t + a tuple?](https://lerner.co.il/2019/06/06/why-do-python-lists-let-you-a-tuple-when-you-cant-a-tuple/).

---

As @khelwood's comment states, the resulting type for `a  += b` is obvious: the type of `a`. So the type of `b` can be flexible. The resulting type of `a + b` is not obvious. Python is a strictly-typed language and hates such ambiguity. The [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) states

> Explicit is better than implicit.

and

> In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.

and

> Although practicality beats purity.

So the current behavior fits Python's Zen pretty well. I note that there is nothing in the Zen about consistency.

Comment: There's something similar in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8710685/6419007).