# Provide declaration - To make a compound assignment illegal, while simple assignment legal

Tags: java, syntax, compiler-errors, compilation, variable-assignment

This question :-  **Make a compound assignment illegal, while simple assignment legal**. Is the inverse to a question which I have already solved. *Provide declarations to make x += i (compound ) legal and x = x + i (simple) not*.

Which can be done by declaring x as short and i as an int. As += contains a hidden cast and x = x + i does not - leading to a compilation error.

I however have been unable to make an assignment where the compound assignment is illegal, while simple assignment is legal. Furthermore to solution to this problem to states :-

***Object x = "hello ";
String i =  "world";
The simple assignment is legal because x + i is of type String and String is assignment compatible with Object.
x = x + i;
The compound assignment is illegal because the left-hand side as an object reference type other than string 
x += i;***

However I can can  compile both with no error?

Comment: The publication date of the text from which this question was taken was  2005. The solution given may have "worked" then but this has since been fixed in modern java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct and the solution is wrong. It's completely legal to say `Object+String`, because that allows you to get a `String`. It's *also* legal to say `Object += String`, because that is the equivalent of `Object = (Object)(Object+String)`, which is valid since `Object+String` (as said before) is `String`, and this can be upcast (widened) to `Object`.

If you want `x = x + i` to be legal and `x += i` illegal, that is actually impossible. As seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8710685/5699679), `x += i` is equivalent to `x = (type of x) (x + i)`. Now, if `x = x + i` is legal, that implies that the type of `x` is a superclass or the same class as the type of `x + i`. That also implies that for `x += i`, the type cast will never fail **iff** x = x + i is legal, as no narrowing conversions will occur if `x = x + i` is legal.

tl;dr: The logic is a bit circular, but it's essentially saying that if `x = x + i` succeeds without casting, then it will also succeed with casting in `x += i`, since you had to check for fitting to `type of x` in the first statement anyways.