# Concern with the vocabulary of JLS

Tags: java, operators, jls, compound-assignment

I always see this strange symbol **§** but never understand wtf means
[image]

---

**Also what E1, T, op means here?**

[image]

### From the post: [Why don't Java's +=, -=, *=, /= compound assignment operators require casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/why-dont-javas-compound-assignment-operators-require-casting?rq=1)

Correct me:

T = data type

op = operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"§" (U+00a7 SECTION SIGN), as its unicode name suggests, just means "section". It is used to refer to specific sections in the JLS.

`E1 op= E2` is a form of "compound assignment expression". I'm sure you've seen compound assignment expressions. They are things like:

```
myCoolVariable += 5
foo *= bar
timeLeft -= 1
```

In the last example, `timeLeft` is `E1`, `-` is `op`, `1` is `E2`. `E1` and `E2` are just expressions. `T`, as the spec says, is specifically *the type of `E1`*. `op` here refers to the operator directly before the `=`. So mostly, your understanding is correct.

The spec is saying that an expression such as `timeLeft -= 1` (assuming `timeLeft` is an `int`) is equivalent to:

```
timeLeft = (int)((timeLeft) - (1))
```

except that `timeLeft` is only evaluated once.