# What is the difference between these two java statement?

Tags: java, type-conversion

```
int s=0;
s+=Math.pow(2,3);
```

this line does not show possible lossy conversion whereas

```
int s=0
s=s+Math.pow(2,3)
```

the above line shows error.
Any reason for this?

Comment: I assume that you forgot to add `;` at the end of each line in the second statement?!

Comment: Reason is implicit casting. Mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/why-dont-javas-compound-assignment-operators-require-casting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the method signature for Math.pow;. It returns the result as a double. You then attempte to return the double as an int, and that is a lossy conversion.